# Url Parse is missing fragment - Python

Tags: python, filenames, urllib, urlparse

I need to save a file with the name of the given acquisition path's file.

Given an URL I would like to parse it and extract the name of the file, here's my code...

I read a JSON parameter and give it to the Parse Url function. The acquisition path is a string.

ParseUrl.py:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse as up
a = up(jtp["AcquisitionPath"])    # => http://127.0.0.1:8000/Users/YodhResearch/Desktop/LongCtrl10min.tiff
print(a)
print(os.path.basename(a))
```

Result:

```
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='127.0.0.1:8000', path='/Users/YodhResearch/Desktop/LongCtrl10min.tiff', params='', query='', fragment='')
[....]
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ParseResult
```

As you can see it Parse the URL but "LongCtrl10min.tiff" is not in the fragment section but is all on the path section. Why is that happening? Maybe because "AcquisitionPath" is a string and UrlParse recognize all as a unique path?

EDIT:

a.path WORKS, I would like to know why I don't get it into the fragment section.

Here's another example:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse as up

string = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/GIULIO%20FERRARI%20FOLDER/Giulio%20_%20CSV/Py%20Script/sparse%20python/tiff_test.tiff_IDAnal#1_IDAcq#10_TEMP_.json"

a = up(string)
print(a)
print(os.path.basename(a))
```

Results:

```
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='127.0.0.1:8000', path='/GIULIO%20FERRARI%20FOLDER/Giulio%20_%20CSV/Py%20Script/sparse%20python/tiff_test.tiff_IDAnal', params='', query='', fragment='1_IDAcq#10_TEMP_.json')
```

See, Now it doesn't get the right fragment that should be: "tiff_test.tiff_IDAnal#1_IDAcq#10_TEMP_.json"

SOLUTION:

Fragment needs '#' symbol! Thanks to all.

Comment: Try `os.path.basename(a.path)`

Comment: It works but I would like to know why I dont get it into fragment section

Comment: What do you mean by `dont get it into fragment section`?

Comment: Because fragment in the url has form `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Users/YodhResearch/Desktop/LongCtrl10min.tiff#fragment`

Comment: get it into... i mean I want to see the file name in the fragment parameter of the urlparse function.

I still don't get why this not happend. I made another example in the question

Comment: Ok Hurlenko I get it what you mean with #fragment. THANKS YOU.

Comment: You may *want* to see that, but you won't, because the file name is not part of the fragment. The fragment *begins* with the `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here: how to identify the components of a URL, and how to create the desired path from those components.

---

First, you are confused over what the fragment actually is. From [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3):

```
The following are two example URIs and their component parts:

         foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
         \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
          |           |            |            |        |
       scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
          |   _____________________|__
         / \ /                        \
         urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

The fragment is *only* the portion following the `#`, not the entire final component of the path.

---

Second, the `urlparse()`function from `urllib` module returns a `ParseResult` object and the `basename()`-method from `os.path` wants a `str` as argument.

What you probably want is to get the path from the `ParseResult`-object. You will get this with `a.path` (the path you have given via `urlparse` is saved in the attribute `path` of the `ParseResult`-object).

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse as up
a = up("http://127.0.0.1:8000/Users/YodhResearch/Desktop/LongCtrl10min.tiff")
print(os.path.basename(a.path))
```

This will output:

> LongCtrl10min.tiff

If you want to include also the fragments, you can do this by explicitly adding this. The fragments are saved in a separated attribute in the `ParseResult` object, i.e. `a.fragment` in your case:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse as up 
a = up("http://127.0.0.1:8000/Users/YodhResearch/Desktop/LongCtrl10min.tiff#anyfragment") 
print(os.path.basename(a.path) + "#" + a.fragment)
```

will output:

> LongCtrl10min.tiff#anyfragment

Comment: It works with a.path but I would like to know why i dont get it into the fragment section.

Comment: I made an EDIT to the question, take a look. Ty :)

Comment: That was not clear from your original question. I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) i didnt know about "#".